# Is there a way to dynamically subtracting paid amount from total amount and get a remaining amount in google sheet

Tags: excel-formula, dynamic, google-sheets-formula, calculation

This is what I tried.

For below table

```
       A         B        C
1   Expenses    Cost    Status

2   Expense1    30000   PAID

3   Expense2    20000   
4   Expense3    7500    
5   Expense4    520

6   Expense5    2300    
7   Expense6    1000    
8   Expense7    11618   
9   Expense8    7939    
10  Expense9    6473    
11  Total       87350  
12  **Remaining Amount  ??**
```

if a column C cell has "PAID", then Substract Total amount(B11) from the PAID(B2) amount.

```
=IF(C2:C10="PAID",MINUS(B11,B2:B10),B11)
```

But this code only subtracts the first PAID amount, do not consider for other cells with PAID

Hoping for help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the formula [SUMIF](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093583?hl=en) in it.

Considering that the `Total` is on column `B11` and the `Remaining` would be on column `B12`, you can use the formula on `B12`:

```
=B11-(SUMIF(C2:C10, "PAID", B2:B10))
```

The number on the remaining will be going down after each expense gets paid.